# Too many one-question users

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, asking, new-users

Lately I've been noticing a lot of users who ask **one** question, and then do nothing else with their account. This means that more and more inactive accounts are lying around, not being used ever, and this kinda annoys me. My request is that new users should be required to answer at the minimum, **five questions**, and have at least **15 reputation** before they can start asking questions of their own. This doesn't guarantee that new users will keep using their accounts, but it will at least help with this issue, and make it so more users are active, rather than just have the account my around. Anyways, that's my idea. So, what does everyone else think?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally, if I may be so blunt, I think it is a very ungood idea, because we are then effectively creating a walled garden, where people have to pay admission to enter.

There is no reason why people need to stick around after their questions get asked/answered. It's the internet! We have unlimited powers of account creation! Do we want people to stick around? Sure. But making it harder for people to participate and ask their own questions just means we are going to lose people, and lessens our ability to make the internet a more awesome place with our super great repository of questions and answers.

While it would be nice if every person ever made an account and asked and answered lots of stuff with good quality content to the end of time, at the same time, this is solving a problem that...isn't really a problem at all.

Comment: The reason it bothers me is that there are all these accounts asking just one question, then never using it again. In my eyes it seems like it would sorta tells newcomers who will actually want to be a part of the active community that the Arqade community is made up of inactive accounts with only one question.

Comment: I don't think that it is nearly as much of a problem as you think - I think the site is growing and attracting users just fine. I have yet to see that impacting our userbase in any sort of measurable way.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Maybe this would become more relevant if it __does__ start affecting the userbase?

Answer (score 8):

This is a solution looking for a problem. Inactive accounts are inactive and harmless, and if an account's only contribution is a negative one those are collected by the system automatically. I see no point in penalising accounts that don't meet arbitrary standards of activity over time.

Comment: The account wouldn't be penalized for being inactive, there would just be starting requirements for new users that would make it so people who register an account just to ask a one question will maybe get more involved once they start answering questions, you know, get the ball rolling. Also, I have no problem with inactive accounts, it's just the accounts that are used to ask __ONE__ question, and __nothing__ else that I have an issue with.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Why does that bother you? It doesn't affect you any.